# Using Geolocation to find nearby Events

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a Rails app with a User model and an Event model amongst others. The Event model columns include location_lat and location_long. I've been trying use geocoder to get events that are close to the user and am not having any success.

In my events.rb file I have:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_event_relationships
    has_many :users, through: :user_event_relationships
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
    has_one_attached :picture
    validates :name, :location, :date_to, :date_from, presence: true
    validate :valid_date_range_required
    geocoded_by :location_lat, location_long
    reverse_geocoded_by :location_lat, :location_long

...
...
end
```

And I've been trying to get the user's ip and then find the nearby event's doing the following:

```
@ip = request.location.ip
@curr_loc = Event.near(@ip[2..-1])
```

I also added a check that when the ip is ::1 (when I'm running locally), it defaults to another ip and this seems to be working. The problem is that when I try using Event.near(@ip[2..-1]), Event.near('Paris') (or any other city) or .near in general nothing is returned. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've looked at the documentation and looked at similar questions on this and other forums but have not found my answer. If you could help or suggest an alternative way to solve this problem that would be appreciated. My teammate tried a javascript function, but it is not working that well. I also thought about using leaflet which I am playing with at the moment.

Comment: The log should tell you the query that Rails executes when you use `Event.near()` ... could you provide that?

Comment: `geocoded_by :location_lat, :location_long`. Altough you should abbreviate longitude to `lng` or `lon` - we don't need yet another abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the `geocoder` gem, but if I understand correctly what you want. From the documentation:

> You can also look up the location of an IP addresses:

```
results = Geocoder.search("172.56.21.89")
results.first.coordinates
=> [30.267153, -97.7430608]
```

So then you can use those coordinates to search nearby events:

```
Event.near([30.267153, -97.7430608], 50)              # venues within 50 miles of a point
Event.near([30.267153, -97.7430608], 50, units: :km)  # venues within 50 kilometres of a point
```

Also try searching e.g. `Event.near("Paris, France")`.